# processing multiple files in minimum time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop. Basically I am writing a program which takes two multifasta files (ref.fasta,query.fasta) which are 3+ GB.....

ref.fasta:

> gi|12345
>   ATATTATAGGACACCAATAAAATT..
>
> gi|5253623
>   AATTATCGCAGCATTA...

..and so on..

query.fasta:

> query
>   ATTATTTAAATCTCACACCACATAATCAATACA
>   AATCCCCACCACAGCACACGTGATATATATACA
>   CAGACACA...

NOw to each mapper I need to give a single part of ref file and the whole query file.
i.e

> gi|12345
>   ATATTATAGGACACCAATA....
>   (a single fasta sequence from ref file)

AND the entire query file.because I want to run an exe inside mapper which takes these both as input.

so do i process ref.fasta outside and then give it to mapper?or some thing else..??
I just need approach which will take minimum time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for your use-case may be to have the query file in [distributed cache](http://bigdataspeak.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/what-is-distributed-cache-in-hadoop/) and get the file object ready in the `configure()`/`setup()` to be used in the `map()`. And have the ref file as normal input.

You may do the following:

In your `run()` add the query file to the distributed cache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(queryFile-HDFS-Or-S3-Path), conf);
```

Now have the mapper class something like following:

public static class MapJob extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper {
                File queryFile;

```
    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf job) {

        Path queryFilePath = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[0];
                    queryFile = new File(queryFilePath.toString());
            }

            @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
            // Use the queryFile object and [key,value] from your ref file here to run the exe file as desired.
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem.

I'd suggest you pre-process your ref file and split it into multiple files (one per sequence). 
Then copy those files to a folder on the hdfs that you will set as your input path in your main method.
Then implement a custom input format class and custom record reader class. Your record reader will just pass the name of the local file split path (as a Text value) to either the key or value parameter of your map method.

For the query file that is require by all map functions, again add your query file to the hdfs and then add it to the DistributedCache in your main method. 
In your map method you'll then have access to both local file paths and can pass them to your exe.

Hope that helps.

I had a similar problem and eventually re-implemented the functionality of blast exe file so that I didn't need to deal with reading files in my map method and could instead deal entire with Java objects (Genes and Genomes) that are parsed from the input files by my custom record reader and then passed as objects to my map function.

Cheers, Wayne.

Comment: hey thanks Wayne...this approach is nice and i tried out..preprocessing the reference file outside is the best way to do it...n BTW I am running MUMmer inside the mapper..Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Hey Wayne...did you call blast executable in your mapper??
if yes how did you do it?? using Streaming jar or is der any other alternative..?